# Accessing WheelEvent.deltaX in TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

In the following code, Visual Studio marks `.deltaY` as an error:

```
$(window).on('mousewheel', (e) => {
     var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
}
```

It seems that the type of `e.originalEvent` is `PopStateEvent`, even though the event has nothing to do with a 'history pop event'.

What's the recommended procedure to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition was incorrect. Its been fixed now. It should be inferred as simply `Event`. See fix : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/2546

You can now do the following:

```
$(window).on('mousewheel', (e) => {
    var delta = (<WheelEvent>e.originalEvent).deltaY;
});
```

What you could have done even without the fix:

```
 var delta = (<any>e.originalEvent).deltaY;
```